# Как лучше подключить базовую станцию к home assistant

Tags: linux, protocol, умный-дом

Подскажите способы решения вопроса по общению базовой станции с home assistant. Базовая станция общается по протоколу loraWan. На сколько удалось узнать нет плагинов для работы на прямую с home asistant. Буду рад любому предложению.

Comment: раз спрашиваете «как лучше?», у вас, видимо, есть уже какой-то вариант (котороый «хуже»). если так, изложите, его, пожалуйста, в тексте вопроса. если не так, измените, пожалуйста, вопрос.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin худший вариант это как то прикрутить гет запросы к home assistant , запросы прикрутить к еще одному серверу а сервер будет общаться с лорой по протоколу. И того получается слишком много устройств